# gap in the plot area for geom_area

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to differentiate the area of the plot color based on the factor variable "Status". I use fill=Status, however, I see a break in the plot area. Any ideas/suggestions on how to avoid this and why is this happening?

```
df1 <- data.frame(Date=seq(as.Date("2016/03/01"), as.Date("2016/03/10"), "day"),
             Storypoints=c(8,14,16,23,28,35,40,44,46,55),
             Status=c(rep("Completed",7), rep("Open",3)))

ggplot(data=df1, mapping = aes(x = Date)) + 
geom_area(aes(y=Storypoints, fill=Status))
```

[image: plot]

Comment: The reason is that there are no data points beween Mar 07 and Mar 08. And because the points on either side of the gap do not belong to the same group, ggplot does not connect them.

Comment: So any ideas on how to get this done? I wish to have a continuous plot with a clear distinction between the two categories

Comment: See my answer. The gap is actually in your data and can only be filled, if you modify your data. Which is probably not what you intend to do.

Comment: Can you explain what your expected outcome is? What should the gap be filled with?

Comment: The expected outcome is that there is a clear distinction (without the gaps) between Completed and Open. Not particular about geom_area. I am open to any other form of plot.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use geom_bar with width=1 to have a continuous area plot that accurately represents your data.

```
ggplot(data=df1, mapping = aes(x = Date)) + 
geom_bar(aes(y=Storypoints, fill=Status), stat="identity",width=1)
```

[image]

Answer (score 7):

The reason is that there are no data points beween Mar 07 and Mar 08. And because the points on either side of the gap do not belong to the same group, ggplot does not connect them. Simply put, the red are ends at Mar 07, the blue one starts at Mar 08 and there is nothing in between.

If you imaging the same plot, but with the gap simply removed, this would mean that the x axis should be labelled both, Mar 07 *and* Mar 08, where the two curves touch.

There is no obvious solution to this  because there is really no data that could be plotted in the gap. If you want to fill the gap, you have to make a decision and the modify your data accordingly.

A possible decision (but most likely not a very good one) would be to simply add a data point such that the read area fills the gap:

```
df1[11, "Date"] <- as.Date("2016-03-08")
df1[11, "Storypoints"] <- 44
df1[11, "Status"] <- "Completed"
ggplot(data=df1, mapping = aes(x = Date)) + 
  geom_area(aes(y=Storypoints, fill=Status), pos = "identity")
```

[image]

But the problem with this is quite clear: The data point that I added should not exist, so what the plot shows on Mar 08 is actually misleading.

I'm not sure there is a satisfactory solution to this. But maybe someone else has a better idea.

Comment: Thank you for the effort. Though the solution clears the gap, it can't be implemented since the red cateogry ends at 44 instead of 40.

Comment: That is exactly what I wrote. There *is* no solution, because the gap is a property of your data. Every way of filling the gap will introduce a "made up" data point, as I did. The whole point of my answer is to show this.

Answer (score -2):

I think it is because ggplot is not able to determine to which status that area belongs, so which color to give it.

I introduced another status and that gave another gap between the filled areas.