# area not properly drawn using geom_area (some area has offset)

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to plot a density function with R and fill some area **below** it. My example is:

```
library(ggplot2)
x = seq(-4, 4, 0.1)
y = dnorm(x, mean=0, sd=1)
myDF = data.frame(x,y,xfill=ifelse(x>-1,x,0))
p <- ggplot(myDF, aes(x,y))
p + geom_line(size=1) + geom_area(aes(x=xfill),fill="red")
```

which looks like  the following image in RStudio.

[image]

I am using RStudio Version  0.99.902 with R version 3.3.1 (2016-06-21) on Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit) running under: Windows >= 8 x64 (build 9200) with package ggplot2_2.1.0

**While creating this question** I got linked to another question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35725964/gap-in-the-plot-area-for-geom-area). Now changing the geom_area call according to one of the answers there to

```
geom_area(aes(x=xfill),fill="red", pos="identity")
```

then my plot looks like
[image]

Finally reducing the x stepsize with

```
x = seq(-4, 4, 0.01)
```

gives me somehow what I want.

[image]

**My Questions:**

1. Any ideas, why there is this problem with the area around 0?
2. why does 'pos="identity"' help here - still missing some area?
3. And have I really solved the problem here?

Comment: I found another problem here (or probably the same), that I am setting xfill to 0, for x values I don't want to plot. Solved this by setting them not matching to the minimum value, in this case: `myDF = data.frame(x,y,xfill=ifelse(x>-1,x,-1))`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can just use `NA` rather than `0` for xfill values you don't want shaded

```
myDF = data.frame(x,y,xfill = ifelse(x > -1, x, NA))

p <- ggplot(myDF, aes(x,y))
p + geom_line(size=1) + geom_area(aes(x=xfill),fill="red")
```

[image]

Also, a small tip: if you plot the area 1st, followed by the line it probably looks better, as the line does not gt partially obscured

```
ggplot(myDF, aes(x,y)) + 
  geom_area(aes(x=xfill),fill="red") + 
  geom_line(size=1)
```

[image]

Comment: NA did the trick, without the need to reduce stepsize or use `pos="identity"`. seems that the 0 was missleading as x coordinate. thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

I think ggplot is making multiple areas and stacking them, which is why `position = identity` helps at it makes the areas overlap instead.

I would change the code to make xfill a binary variable that specifies which fill is requires. Reduce the step size to remove the gap.

```
x <- seq(-4, 4, 0.01)
y <- dnorm(x, mean=0, sd=1)
myDF <- data.frame(x,y,xfill=ifelse(x>-1,TRUE,FALSE))
ggplot(myDF, aes(x,y, fill = xfill)) + 
       geom_line(size=1) +
       geom_area()
```

Comment: This produces two separately colored areas, but not exactly what I want. I would want the right side to be red and the left side not to be coloured at all.

Comment: \you could set `alpha` to zero to not show the unwanted colour